# How can I use navigator.getMedia in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I have a problem when implementing navigator.getMedia in angular. Which would be the correct way?.

```
public promiseGetUserMediaOld(constraints: any) {
    navigator.getMedia =
      navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getMedia(constraints, resolve, reject);
  }
```

the error is "Property 'getMedia' does not exist on type 'Navigator'"

Comment: Declare const navigator: any

Comment: `const getMedia = ...; getMedia(...);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax would be `navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia`

> The MediaDevices.getUserMedia() method prompts the user for permission to use a media input which produces a MediaStream with tracks containing the requested types of media.
>
> That stream can include, for example, a video track (produced by
> either a hardware or virtual video source such as a camera, video
> recording device, screen sharing service, and so forth), an audio
> track (similarly, produced by a physical or virtual audio source like
> a microphone, A/D converter, or the like), and possibly other track
> types.
>
> It returns a Promise that resolves to a MediaStream object. If the
> user denies permission, or matching media is not available, then the
> promise is rejected with NotAllowedError or NotFoundError DOMException
> respectively.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/media-devices/#getusermedia

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  // Put variables in global scope to make them available to the browser console.
const constraints = window.constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};
errorString = '';

ngOnInit() {}

handleSuccess(stream) {
  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
  console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
  console.log(`Using video device: ${videoTracks[0].label}`);
  window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

handleError(error) {
  if (error.name === 'OverconstrainedError') {
    const v = constraints.video;
    errorMsg(`The resolution ${v.width.exact}x${v.height.exact} px is not supported by your device.`);
  } else if (error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
    errorMsg('Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and ' +
      'microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in ' +
      'order for the demo to work.');
  }
  errorMsg(`getUserMedia error: ${error.name}`, error);
}

errorMsg(msg, error) {
  this.errorString = msg;
  if (typeof error !== 'undefined') {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async init(e) {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    this.handleSuccess(stream);
    e.target.disabled = true;
  } catch (e) {
    this.handleError(e);
  }
}


}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/media-recorder-ukdruh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts